# Problema al ejecutar dotnet ExampleApp.dll desde terminal

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, docker

Cuento con un problema:

Estoy aprendiendo el uso de `docker` y quería crear un `dockerfile`. En un vídeo observé que usaban los comandos (Ejemplifico con `ExampleApp` para no escribir el nombre largo del proyecto):

```
dotnet restore
dotnet publish -c Release -o out
```

y todo bien, en la parte posterior al ejecutar

```
dotnet out/ExampleApp.dll

**Unhandled exception. System.ArgumentNullException: String reference not set to an instance of a String. (Parameter 's')
   at System.Text.Encoding.GetBytes(String s)
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in C:\Users\Franklin\Desktop\ClinicaLaEsperanzaBackend\ServicioRestClinicaLaEsperanza\Program.cs:line 86**

**Unhandled exception. System.ArgumentNullException: String reference not set to an instance of a String. (Parameter 's')
   at System.Text.Encoding.GetBytes(String s)**
```

La línea de código es la siguiente:

```
var jwtKey=  builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("JwtSettings:SecretKey");

var keyBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(jwtKey);
```

En el entorno de desarrollo no tengo ese error (y no es que me he equivocado en clave-valor del json)
Así también el ejecutable (`ExampleApp.exe`) que se genera con:

```
dotnet publish -c Release -o out
```

Se ejecuta de manera normal, únicamente sucede con el `.dll`
Gracias de antemano. Estoy usando NET Core 6. y en el entorno de desarrollo no me sucede ese comportamiento.

Espero su ayuda para saber el porqué del problema y cómo abordarlo.

Comment: y esa configuracion tambien esta para el modo deploy????

Comment: Edita la pregunta y agrega lo que tienes en el `appsettings.json`. Saludos.